# Restheart how to delete an aggregration

Tags: mongodb, restheart

I have a number of aggregations defined in my mongodb instance and I would like to delete one of them.

So for example if I had 3 defined in the collections _properties metadata and I wanted to get rid of the second one how would I do it.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example-aka-mcve-minimal-complete-and-ver)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want but...
{
 "aggrs": [
 {
   "stages": [],
   "type": "pipeline",
   "uri": "myFirstAgg"
  },
{
   "stages": [],
   "type": "pipeline",
   "uri": "mySecondAgg"
  },
{
   "stages": [],
   "type": "pipeline",
   "uri": "myThirdAgg"
  }  
 ]
}


I want to remove the #mySecondAgg' section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to create an aggregation you define the `aggrs` array as a collection property.

`PATCH /db/coll {"aggrs": [ {<aggr1>}, {<aggr2>}, {<aggr3>} ] }`

to delete one you just need to update the `aggrs` property

`PATCH /db/coll {"aggrs": [ {<aggr1>}, {<aggr3>} ] }`

you can also use the [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) array update operator:

`PATCH /db/coll {"$pull": { "aggrs": { "uri": "mySecondAgg" } } }`

Comment: Thanks, Andrea - I had kind of already come to the same conclusion (although not quite an elegant as your solution) I guess I thought I was meant to use the delete method of the API.